# How to change the size of an array after the user selects values in the userform of Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to Excel-VBA. I want some code to adjust the array size as per the users input in userform. For example, if `combox1` has 50 words and user selects only 4 words from that, this will be collected in `lstbox1`.
Then, if `combox2` had 10 numbers (e.g. 1, 2, 3 ...), and the user selects only the first 3 numbers, then they will collected in `listbox2`.

Now i have these values in the table:

```
colA  dad mom kill had
colB  1 2 3 4 5
```

Now i want some code to create a combination for this `colA` and `colB`.
For that, I have to create array and assign size for that at first. I don't know how much the user will select.

Comment: If you need to adjust an array in VBA then you just need the `ReDim` statement: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx For the rest of what you want to achieve you will need some more VBA code. The following website might be a good starting point for that: http://www.homeandlearn.org/

Comment: ok.i visit t then reply u

Comment: You can use the selected items for each, and use the MAX of the 2 values, so as Ralph says, Redim array(max(combobox1.selecteditems.count,combobox2.selecteditems.count))  You'd need to add from the largest to the array, so if cbo1 contains 5, and cbo2 contains 3, then you'd need to loop using cbo1 selected items, then trapping if the count is > than cbo2 count.  If counter<=cbo2.selecteditems.count then array(...... =    I shall put some code on when I get chance.

Comment: no i collect the seleted items from combox1 to listbox1. and combox2 selected items in listbox2

Comment: i want a combination results in worksheet 1

Comment: The following might be of help in `selecting` items on a list, `read` from a list and `write` a list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703491/excel-vba-exporting-2-column-listbox-to-separate-worksheet/35704158#35704158

Comment: no no i think i didn't explain my problem correctly

Comment: see i had combobox1 with multi select option .it contains 50 states name.if i select 4outof 50 .selected 4 states will tansfered to listbox1.now i want to create an array1 for listbox one.like this for combobox2 also

Comment: suppose they selecte the 50 states i have to change array size to 0to50.

Comment: is there anybody help me?